# How does any syncronous request works in asycrounous microservices enviorment?

Tags: microservices, software-design, distributed-system

Lets see I have a microservices  A,B,C and D, which communicate asynchronously using message broker (Kafka). if service A is UI facing service accept synchronous request for a transaction which  depend on B and C.  now here service A put a message in message broker queue which is already having some message to process then request has to wait till we get response from other services.
how would you design this type of microservice communication ?
if we required both type of communication synchronous and asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

> how would you design this type of microservice communication?

It depends. *Synchronous communication* as you describe is using a *request-response pattern* while the *asynchronous communication* usually (not always) use a *publish-subscribe pattern* in situations like yours.

Whether you can or can not use a *request-response* pattern depends on your requirements of **response time**.

Whether you can or can not use a *publish-subscribe* in your *UI facing service* depends on technical requirements, e.g. if you can use a library like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), [RSocket](http://rsocket.io/), an MQTT client or something else with *pub-sub semantics*.

For me, it feels more natural to use any kind of *pub-sub* protocol in these situations.